# how to send a scheduled report via email to user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, report

i am trying to send a schedule report (containing charts and graphs)  every week to the user via email using Laravel

so , what is the best way to do that

thank you

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can make a command and register it in the app/Console/Kernel.php

1)
app/Console/Commands/Reporter.php

```
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class Reporter extends Command {

protected $name = 'Reporter';

protected $description = 'This is a test.';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function fire()
{
    Mail::send('emails.pdf', function($message) use ($path) {
        $message->to('testuser1@test.com', 'testuser')->subject
        ('pdf Report '. Carbon::now()->format('m-d-Y'));
        $message->attach($path);
        $message->from('no-reply@test.com','test-tech');
    });
    Storage::disk('pdf')->delete(Storage::disk('pdf')->allFiles());

    $this->info('Mail has fired.');
}
}
```

2.app/Console/Kernel.php

```
protected $commands = [
'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
'App\Console\Commands\Reporter',
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
$schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();

$schedule->command('Reporter')->weekly();
```

}

you can create pdf with mpdf
https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf

```
use PDF;
class ReportController extends Controller {
public function generate_pdf()
 {
  $data = [
  'foo' => 'bar'
  ];
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
  return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
  }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for your response , i use link to render the chart as image so every thing work fine when i run the task schedule locally but when i deploy it to the server any image inside the pdf break down , do u have any idea or suggestion ?? –